# how to share own emoji's to other application like whats app from chat head

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application  to share own emoji's on other messaging  apps like whats app (same as hike share emoji's from chat head). Any one have idea for it or any link from where i could get idea. how I get text field in other app.

Answer (score 1):

You just create symbols or letters of your emoji in your app . And Just detect the symbol or letter in your app and create emoji in your app. After this just send the symbols or letters to send and detect in client side app and create emoji against it.

> Example
>
> :P <-- this symbol create tongue smile just detect these words and
>   create emoji against them in your app.

For this you can save definitions of your emoji in your app already

But you have to take care of others Emoji symbols like if you want to send it on Whats app for this your symbol must match of their symbol of emoji too